# Without Coordinator issued Milestones, how will a post-COO node know if it is in sync?

Tags: iri-node, milestones, coordinator

At the moment, a node can be defined as 'sync' with the network based on the last solid subtangle Milestone.

Without the Coordinator issued Milestones, how will a post-COO node know if it is in sync?

How will it know how far ahead or behind the network that it really is?

Answer (score 1):

So far, the solution isn't found/decided yet. In other words there is no implementation yet.

That being said, every transaction have a "height" property defined as the length of the shortest path to genesis. A measurement of the sync state of a node can be based on the (average) height of it's (solid) tips.

The exact formula still to be found, but something like the average height of all solid tips can be a good first approximation.

Comment: Just mathematical intuition. Note that [Alon Galsky (reseacher from IF) also suggest to use height of tips](https://github.com/iotaledger/cliri/issues/13#issuecomment-446641206).